# Loading 5 million+ Emails into Salesforce

Tags: email, heroku-connect, postgres

We have millions of emails(actual HTML emails that were sent to clients) stored in our old CRM Siebel but since we are migrating away from Siebel ,now we want to migrate those emails to Salesforce so that our agents can search them inside Salesforce. We are thinking of having a postgres SQL database on Heroku and store those emails and somehow be able to search them inside Salesforce.
Does anybody have some options for me to consider.Appreciate any response.

Comment: Please provide more details about your use case. Are you migrating away from Siebel? Is there a reason for why you don’t create those “emails” as contacts in Salesforce?

Comment: These are actual emails that were previously sent to clients(.HTML files) .

Comment: If you load the emails as EmailMessage records, [the body](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_fields_lex.htm&type=5) will be indexed and can be searched on. SF expects the body to be plain text. You can either convert HTML to plaintext when importing or dump HTML as plaintext (e.g. HTML tags will be treated as email body). In the latter case search results and rendering of the email will be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to insert the emails as `ContentVersion` records.

Provided the email body is less than 5MB, the ContentVersion (aka File) is [searchable](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_searching.htm&type=5) when the extension is .html

The `ContentVersion` parent (automatically created) is called a `ContentDocument` and it can be associated to most other objects via a `ContentDocumentLink` junction object, enabling the email file to appear in the Files related list on that object

Of course, File storage is limited in your org and if the number of GB exceeds your license, you'll need to purchase additional capacity. Check how much you have (and %used) in `Setup | Company Settings`

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Seems like a viable option

Comment: Also we only have email addresses or phone numbers of those clients whom these emails were sent . Should we create an Account parent to link these ContentDocumentLink or a new standalone object?

Comment: why link them at all? There isn't a requirement that ContentDocument be linked.  Furthermore, if you created a Contact record - you'd have to synthesize a LastName (required field) and you would immediately incur a Data Storage penalty of 2K * 5M = 10 GB just for the Contact recs

or - look at the `Individual` object in lieu of the Contact object

Comment: But after i upload all the emails as files and later want to search what emails were sent to a client with email X or Ph no. Y, how do i do it?

Comment: Ok, then use Contact or Individual object for linking.